# BGL: Using bundled properties to store vertex descriptor of another vertex

Tags: c++, vertex, boost-graph

I am trying to create a tree graph using `boost::adjacency list` and bundled properties to store the parent for every vertex, I want to store vertex descriptors in a way that they wont invalidate in case I remove a vertex, so I use `boost::listS`, the code should look something like this

```
// custom vertex for tree graphs
struct tree_vertex_info{
    // descriptor of parent vertex
    boost::graph_traits<Tree>::vertex_descriptor parent_in_tree;
};
// the tree graph type
typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::directedS
        tree_vertex_info, boost::no_property, graph_info> Tree;
```

But this would not work since Tree must be defined after the struct definition. Is there any other way to do it with bundled properties? I thought I could use an int variable instead of vertex_descriptor type to store vertex_descriptors but since I use `boost::listS` to store them I am not sure if can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theoretically, you could have something like this:

```
struct tree_vertex_info;  // forward-declaration

typedef boost::adjacency_list<
  boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::directedS, 
  tree_vertex_info, boost::no_property, graph_info> Tree;

struct tree_vertex_info {
  boost::graph_traits<Tree>::vertex_descriptor parent_in_tree;
};
```

However, this would require the `boost::adjacency_list` class template to support *incomplete types* (which is what `tree_vertex_info` is while there is only a forward-declaration, until the compiler reaches the complete declaration of it). As far as I know, the `boost::adjacency_list` class does not support incomplete types (and I know that implementation quite a bit, and I don't think it would work) and it is certainly not guaranteed to support them.

I am actually working on a new version of `boost::adjacency_list` which I call `boost::adjacency_list_BC` because it's based on Boost.Container containers, and it will support incomplete types. However, it is still kind at a beta stage (follow [here](https://github.com/mikael-s-persson/boost_graph_ext_mp) or [here](https://github.com/mikael-s-persson/graph/tree/trees-BC-and-more)), and the latest versions of Boost.Container seem to have broken something that I still need to figure out. By the way, I also have a number of BGL tree data-structures as well as new BGL concepts and traits for trees (since you seem to be implementing a kind of tree).

Also, if your motivation for this is really what you have there (the "parent-in-tree"), then you should be using `boost::bidirectionalS` in your `adjacency_list` to be able to get from a child vertex to its parent (that's what `boost::bidirectionalS` means, you get a [BidirectionalGraph](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/graph/doc/BidirectionalGraph.html)).

Finally, to actually solve this situation you are in, you'll have to use a type-erasure technique. A simple off-the-shelf way to do it is to use `boost::any` to erase the type of the vertex_descriptor, like so:

```
struct tree_vertex_info{
  // descriptor of parent vertex
  boost::any parent_in_tree;
};

// the tree graph type
typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::directedS
        tree_vertex_info, boost::no_property, graph_info> Tree;
```

Just look up [Boost.Any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/any.html) for instructions on using it.

> I thought I could use an int variable instead of vertex_descriptor type to store vertex_descriptors but since I use listS to store them I am not sure if can.

No, you cannot. You cannot depend on the vertex_descriptor type being anything in particular (e.g., you cannot assume it is an integer type, let alone "int"). I happen to know that vertex_descriptor is usually either an iterator type (such as `std::list<T>::iterator`) or a size-type (like `std::size_t` or `std::vector<T>::size_type`), but that's an implementation detail that you should not and cannot rely on.

Comment: `boost::any` seems to have solved the problem! My first thought was to use bidirectional graph but since I am trying to implement a dynamic algorithm for maintaining minimal length paths this doesn't quite work well because when I would need the parent of an edge I'd have to examine all the adjacent edges and then examine which of them lead to a lowest depth vertex, and in this case I would have to store the depths. 
Thank you a lot for the help! Except for the solution you also gave me a clue about things that I wasn't sure!